# UPDATE statement with ROUND mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, select, sql-update

I'm having a problem where I need to use ROUND to round a column to one decimal place.  It's working with a SELECT statement and I can get FORMAT to work with a SELECT statement but I can't get it to work with an UPDATE statement, which is what I need to use it with.  Here's my code:

```
update _transrecords
LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON V0_X1_PK = V0_X1_FK 
set f6sp = ROUND(f6*V0_x1_a3, 1)

select               
ROUND(F6 * V0_X1_A3, 1) as F6sp
from _TransRecords   
LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON V0_X1_PK = V0_X1_FK
```

After that I need to get rid of the decimal in F6sp where F6sp has a zero after the decimal place, but it's not working with the SELECT or UPDATE statement.  I'm trying to use REGEXP to find where a decimal value is zero.  Here's my statements for that:

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(F6sp,0)  AS  F6sp 
FROM _TransRecords 
WHERE F6sp REGEXP '.period.zero.$'

UPDATE _TransRecords 
SET F6sp = ROUND(F6sp) 
WHERE F6sp REGEXP '.period.zero.$'
```

I've already searched here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html

and numerous stackoverflow questions, it hasn't helped yet.  I'm not getting error messages on my statements though.  The REGEXP is just returning an empty set.

I've also tried adding two periods between the regexp expression but I still get an empty set.

```
WHERE F6sp REGEXP '.period..zero.$'
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `f65p`?

Comment: decimal(17,5) and puts it out to 5 decimal places with the update statement but not the update statement.

Comment: *not the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not using REGEXP:

```
UPDATE _TransRecords 
SET F6sp = ROUND(F6sp) 
WHERE INSTR(F6sp,'.0')>0;
```

Should do it.

Comment: What version of MySQL would that be from?  I'm using an old version, I have to figure out what it is.  When I run it as an update statement in the code it throws an error at index and when I run a select statement in MySQL Control Center it throws the same error.

Comment: My Control Center version is 0.9.4-beta

Comment: It's not working with the update statement but it does work a select statement in the exact places I need it to.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with a `decimal` column.  The number of decimal places is determined by the type, not the value.  So, you'll just get 0.00000, for zero.

When you query the data, you can do:

```
select format(f6sp, (case when mod(f6sp, 1.0) < 0.1 then 0 else 1 end))
```

MySQL (and SQL in general) does not let you store numeric formats as part of the column type.

Comment: So I guess I'm going to have to write my report out with select statements instead of setting the using the update statements we would normally use.

Comment: @Spitz  . . . I would suggest that you put a view over the tables and do the formatting in the view.

Answer (score 0):

A database is for storing data.  An application is for formatting what you get from the database.

A few formatting tools are available in SQL; don't expect everything to be available.